# I need to match multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to solve the following problem. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I have 4 columns (A through D) with data that looks like this

A     B      C       D
6     7      1       0
3     6      1       0
7     3      1       1

The data in columns C and D are attached to B, and what I would like to do is to rearranged those columns so they follow the order in column A. In other words, what I would like to get at the end is this:

A     B      C       D
6     6      1       0
3     3      1       1
7     7      1       0

That's it! I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to pretend your data is in Sheet1 starting at A1.

Create a new Sheet and these four formulas in A1 to D1

```
A1: =Sheet1!A1
B1: =VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$B:$D,1,FALSE)
C1: =VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$B:$D,2,FALSE)
D1: =VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$B:$D,3,FALSE)
```

You can then fill these down as necessary. Hopefully this is an acceptable solution for you!

Comment: One thing to note, if there is duplicates, the VLOOKUP will stop at the first match it finds. This may or may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but can you just cut and paste columns B, C, and D into the desired locations?

Alternatively, if columns C and D have formulas based off of the value of column B and column B is always supposed to equal column A, you could simply set the cells of column B to equal column A (set B1 to `=A1`, etc).

Comment: If he only had four rungs he would probably do it manually. I'm guessing that this is just sample data for a larger worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Nate was right, I have a large worksheet, with hundreds of rows. Cheers!